Is it possible to configure a pre-installed Windows 11 machine with a local account anymore?
I'm doing the required first-user configuration when first booting a machine with Windows 11 (and S Mode) pre-installed on the machine.
Windows seems to be trying its hardest to force me to use a Windows account, for my own hardware purchased with a legitimate Windows license.
All of the techniques that seemed to work in the past no longer work:

I can't just say I don't have internet
Neither Shift-F10 nor Shift-Fn-F10 seems to do anything on my Aspire 3 15.
Even using the on-screen keyboard with either of these combinations doesn't yield anything
And none of the network-disabling techniques have worked either - just as this comment suggests, it seems the home version is very firm on this point.

Is a simple local account, not linked to a Microsoft account still possible when configuring Windows 11 pre-installed with S Mode enabled on a machine?

Yes; Rufus has integrated a script that makes this extremely easy when installing Windows

I had to configure a new install recently and the solution that worked for me was to unplug power to the router. I can't attest that such an action will work again, however.

Ran into this just recently. @Ramhound, it seems that the Rufus approach applies to installing a new copy of Windows but not to setting up a pre-installed copy? Is that correct?   TIA.
OP, I had a pre-installed copy of Windows. During setup I had to accept the stuff MS wanted to ram down my computer's throat, then go into User Manager and create a new local user.  Other than one or two bits of glitchery, it seems to have done the job.

Running the oobe\bypassnro command is still the easiest option in my opinion. Guide aside from Rufus' integrated script.

@Victor Sorry for the error in the title. I've corrected it to clarify that I'm talking about first-user configuration when first booting a machine with Windows 11 (and S Mode) pre-installed on the machine.

The first section below describes a solution where I create a new Microsoft account with random data, then create a local adminstrator account and delete the Microsoft one.
After this, I put some notes on how one might be able to avoid creating the random Microsoft account altogether.

I created a new Microsoft Account using random data everywhere. It was still necessary to link the account to an "existing" email address. I used my own email address -- but it's possible that random data here would also be accepted. I recommend holding on to all the random information until you are successful at creating a local administrator and deleting the random account. From a Git Bash prompt on another machine, I used cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd '!@#$%^&*()_+{}:;>?[:alnum:]' | head -c 30 to generate random information; you may prefer a different approach.
Then, the laptop went through an update process which took some time.
After that, I followed Steve Rindsberg's advice and added another user. Again, the suggestion was to link their Microsoft account, but I selected these options:

Press Windows key, type "Users", then click on "Other Users", then click "Add account"
"How will this person sign in?": Click "I don't have this person's sign-in information"
"Create account -- someone@example.com": Click "Add a user without a Microsoft account"
Name "LastName" (Used my family name here)
Password. Left this blank.
Click: "Change account type", then select "Administrator"
Shut down. (Or log out)
Log in as "LastName". No password was required.
"Choose privacy settings for your device." Turned off everything here (except required diagnostics, which are still sent in the off state.)
(you can skip this step) Once logged in, again went to the "Other Users" page as above. But could not delete the other user because they need to "sign out" (which is strange, because I rebooted and did not log in as that user.)
Switched to the random user, using the pin I created when setting up the machine. Then signed out from that user. (If your laptop has SMode and you want to disable it, it's probably best to do this with the random user at this point, rather than creating a second random user.)
Signed back in as "LastName".  Returned to the "Other Users" page. Selected the random user and clicked "Remove".
In the "Delete account and data" dialog, clicked "Delete account and data."

The laptop I purchased came with Windows (and S Mode) installed by default.  If you want to disable S Mode (as I did), I recommend doing so at the point mentioned above, rather than following the instructions below. But these instructions described my own process. When I tried to install Firefox, I needed to switch out of S Mode. It turns out that you ALSO need a Microsoft account to switch out of S Mode. At this point, I either had forgotten exactly what my Microsoft account was, or it was considered a corporate account, so I:

Created yet another random account with a random email and password, as described above.
Used that account to switch out of S Mode.
Went to microsoft.com, and signed in with that account's username and password.
Went to devices and unlinked the device, also unlinking the account from Microsoft Store.
Rebooted the computer, confirming that the machine did NOT suggest that I sign into that account, as suggested by this answer.

At this point, I believe I have an ordinary traditional unsecured Windows machine.

If you don't want to even create a random Microsoft account, I recommend:

Don't enter any details for your WiFi.
Try the various Alt-F10 techniques mentioned in the question
If you get to a page asking for your name instead of your email, go ahead and create the account and don't cancel out -- you might not be able to get back to that page!

I was, at one point in the process, able to have it start creating a local account. But I was not able to reproduce this process. Roughly, this is how I was able to get to that point:
These are the steps I followed with my Windows 11 Aspire 3 15:

When asked about the country, I selected "United States" and clicked "Yes".
When asked, "Is this the right keyboard layout or input method?" I selected "US" and selected "Yes."
Skipped second keyboard layout.
Had already enabled wifi on an earlier pass, and I have enough neighbors with WiFi that I likely couldn't skip this step anyway. So this time, it just skipped to the next screen without even mentioning wifi.
Clicked on "Sign in"
When coming to the dreaded "Let's add your Microsoft account" screen, I clicked on the "No account? Create one!" link.
At this point, it asked me for my name and then instructed me to create a secure password. (but suggesting that it would be better to use an online account).

I think proceeding from this point might create a local only account.
But when I repeat these instructions so as to capture details, it is now asking for a email address rather than a first name! I force-turned off my computer, and this did something to the install process.

Windows 11 in S mode can only work with a Microsoft Account, not a local account. If you installed Windows 11 in S Mode, then you never can bypass the microsoft account requirement. The only way around it is to first download Windows 11 Home or Pro installer, install that to the computer, and use that setup. Alternatively, you complete the login with microsoft account, go to the windows store to install the program that can get the system out of S mode, and after that, create a local account.

@LPChip - The author didn't install Windows in S Mode. He would have received the device with Windows installed already in S Mode. The device comes with Windows 11 Home. The specifications for the page suggest S Mode is not enabled. You cannot switch from S Mode being disabled to enabled only Enabled to Disabled (once).

@Ramhound the answer says otherwise. I quote: "When I tried to install Firefox, I needed to switch out of S Mode. It turns out that you ALSO need a Microsoft account to switch out of S Mode."

Yes, I know, normally if it comes with Windows 11 Home with S Mode it’s advertised as so

Josiah: If you have a Microsoft account and wanted a local account, then why not just go to setting and switch to a local account?

@DavidAnderson That is exactly what this suggestion recommends -- switching to a local account and then deleting the Microsoft account that I feel should not be required to install Microsoft.

@LPChip is correct. I did not install S Mode.  I received the device with Windows already installed in S Mode.

@LPChip I have edited the answer to clarify it on this point.

Josiah: But you created a new account, then deleted the old account. I am asking why you did not just go to the settings and make the old account a local account?

@DavidAnderson Good point. I didn't realize I would need to disable S Mode at that point.  But I've edited the answer to try to guide new users in the right direction, even though I'm unable to write verified step-by-step instructions until next time I have to go through this with a new machine.

@DavidAnderson  I suppose that, after creating a random account, one could then edit the local account to put in name, etc.  I didn't think of that option either.  It just felt cleaner to have the local account never linked to MS -- although in the end, I DID have to link the local account to MS as well, because it was in S Mode.  Again, next time I have to go through this, I'll likely update this answer based on my experience.

@DavidAnderson note, that because S mode was still active at that point, Windows would tell you to first disable bitlocker which you cannot do because S mode is on.

@LPChip: I do not understand your previous comment. I have installed Windows 11 Home with S mode and BitLocker is turned on. I am able to switch to a local account without any problems.

@DavidAnderson - BitLocker cannot be enabled on Windows 11 Home, Device Encryption was enabled, minor point.

@DavidAnderson yes, but when you attempt in doing so, Windows will warn you that it is better to disable bitlocker first because you may get into a situation where you can't get in anymore. I had to do it before. I disabled bitlocker, got the computer out of S mode, and then was stuck enabling it again because apparently it was drive encryption, not bitlocker.

It has something to do with the bitlocker key being stored in the microsoft account. Something that happens on Windows 11 Home in S mode after you do the OOBE and login with a microsoft account.

LPChip: I think @Ramhound is right. Device Encryption was enabled. Not BitLocker. I see you two have visited this issue before. I did not have to leave S mode to switch to a local user. I was able to document the steps here. I am using Windows 11 Home 24H2 in S mode.

The create a local account, when your computer has been preinstalled with Windows 11 in S mode, start the computer for the first time without being connected to the internet. If you have a ethernet cable connected to your computer, then unplug this cable before turning on.
Follow the instructions given below. These instructions were tested using Windows 11 Home in S mode.
You should reach the following screen at some point after turning on the computer for the first time.

Press the key combination control+shift+F3 to boot to Audit Mode. This may take a while. You should eventually reach the Administrator's Desktop shown below.

Boot to Recovery by holding down the shift key while restarting the computer. You should reach a screen shown below.

Select Troubleshoot→Advanced options→Command Prompt. You should see the Command Prompt window shown below.

Enter the command below.
bcdedit

Example output from this command is shown below.

Under Windows Boot Loader there is the following.
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS

If the drive letter for your osdevice is not C:, then substitute your drive letter when entering C:\Windows in the commands that follow. Similarly, if the path for your systemroot is not \WINDOWS, the substitute your path when entering C:\Windows in the commands that follow.
Edit the registry by entering the following commands. Note: Do not make any substitutions when entering the reg add command given below. Enter this command exactly as shown.
type C:\Windows\System32\oobe\BypassNRO.cmd
reg load HKU\TempHive C:\Windows\System32\config\SOFTWARE
reg add HKU\TempHive\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\OOBE /v BypassNRO /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
reg unload HKU\TempHive

An example of entering these commands is given below.

Enter the following command to close the Command Prompt window.
exit

You should return to the following screen.

Select Continue. You should return to the Audit Mode Administrator's Desktop shown below.

In the System Preparation Tool window, shown below, select OK.

After a while, you can continue setting up Windows. When you reach a screen similar to the one shown below, select I don't have internet.

Later, instead of asking for you to sign in, the follow display will appear asking to create a local account.

When I encounter my Desktop for the first time some of the icons were missing, as shown below.

After connecting to the internet by plugging in the ethernet cable, the screen changed to the following.

After connecting to the internet, you probably should visit Windows Update.
Below is an image of the Windows Specifications. This image was taken after signing in to my local account.

The image below shows device encryption is turned on, but has not occurred. To start encryption, sign in to a Microsoft account. This will switch the user out of using a local account. A recovery key will be sent to the Microsoft account.

The image below shows the result after signing in to a Microsoft account. Device encryption has started. I verified that a recovery key was sent to the Microsoft account by going to https://aka.ms/myrecoverykey.

